# Missing events when intercepting state changes in angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using a the normal interceptor approach to restrict access to a certain state and only authenticated users are allowed. When not authenticated, the user gets redirect to a login page. This works fine.

I'm also listening to state change events to show a loading spinner. Which works fine as well. However, with a redirect the  `$stateChangeStart` is triggered twice, but `$stateChangeSuccess`, `$stateChangeError` and even `$viewContentLoaded` just once.

There is an issue when trying to access a secure state when the login page is currently loaded. The `$stateChangeStart` event is triggered, but the`$stateChangeSuccess`, `$stateChangeError` or `$viewContentLoaded` events aren't, making my spinner load for eternity. See the sample below.

```
// module.config()
$stateProvider.state({
    name: 'home',
    url: '/home',
    controller: function() {},
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
});
$stateProvider.state({
    name: 'login',
    url: '/login',
    controller: function() {},
    templateUrl: 'login.html'
});
$stateProvider.state({
    name: 'secure',
    url: '/secure',
    controller: function() {},
    templateUrl: 'secure.html'
});

// module.run()
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function() {
    console.log('$stateChangeStart: starting loading spinner');
});
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
    console.log('$stateChangeSuccess: stopping loading spinner');
});
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function() {
    console.log('$stateChangeError stopping loading spinner');
});
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    console.log('$viewContentLoaded stopping loading spinner');
});
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {
    if (toState.name == 'secure') {
        $state.go('login');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

I can workaround by manually triggering an event during redirect to stop my spinner, but I would expect one of the other events are triggered automatically when calling `preventDefault()` Explicitly enforcing a notification in the redirect state change with `$state.go('login', {}, {notify: true});` doesn't work too. The events are not in sync with a redirect when intercepting the state change. Hence my second observation when the start event is triggered twice, but the others just once.

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` stops the transition happening doesn't it? Therefore the spinner will not stop spinning.

Comment: @tommyd456 Exactly. And afaik there isn't some sort of 'transition canceled' event triggered either, so no way for me to know when to stop the spinner.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    if (toState.name == 'secure') {
        $state.go('login');  
    } else {
        //go to toState
    }
});
```

This approach will stop the transitions first and then start a new transition which should in turn activate the listeners that will stop your spinner.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to enforce a state reload in the interceptor as follows:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {
    if (toState.name == 'secure') {
        $state.go('login', {}, { reload: true });
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

However, this still might pose an issue, since `$stateChangeStart` is executed twice. Also, because the reload might trigger unneeded service calls in the state's `resolve`

Could this be bug or missing feature in angular-ui-router?